# OAuth2 and Yelp access in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, yelp

I'm  trying to use the Yelp API. v3 is using OAuth2 but I'm not sure about the processing of all the data.

This is the code to get the token associated to the key:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(  ENV[ 'YELP_APP_ID' ], 
                                  ENV[ 'YELP_APP_SECRET' ],
                                  :token_url => ENV[ 'YELP_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL' ],
                                  :site => ENV[ 'YELP_ENDPOINT_URL' ],
                                  :access_token_method => :post, 
                                  :grant_type => :client_credentials)

puts("this is my blabla #{client}")
code =  client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => "http://localhost:4000")
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:4000")
puts("this is my blabla #{token.token}")
OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, token.token)
```

`TOKEN_URL` is `/oauth2/token` and `ENDPOINT` is `https://api.yelp.com`.

I receiving a code like:

```
69gSGF4oPNzyd2GTK824wlYOAwX8ibbsdEF5bmPsqUVj22WqK6X5alGRv0cahoXL-W9z0TVHvMxgWZNk2xpwDPJFLKbZBCuDfHQEDImlG6dPajgp23B-NFGzj
```

First, can I be sure to be granted with the right token?

I am not sure also about the `redirect_uri`. My code will run an Heroku but now it's on my local machine.

Can I use something like `:@domain` instead of `local`?

I am asking this because, when sending a request to Yelp, it always gives me the same result. I ask for Sushi and it sends back five restaurants.

I want first to make sure that my OAuth2 processing is correct.

Comment: It's not necessary to apologize for your (lack of) experience. We don't care if you're new, we just want well researched and asked questions. Also, it's not necessary, and is in fact discouraged, to use greetings, valedictions or signatures. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum, it's an online reference book where you're helping write articles solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for You:

```
app_id = "Your APP ID HERE"
app_secret ="Your APP secret here"


import requests

def get_yelp_token(app_id, app_secret):           
    payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': app_id, 'client_secret': app_secret}
    file1 = requests.post('https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token?', params = payload)
    print file1.text 

get_yelp_token(app_id, app_secret)
```

Comment: I am not able ot make it work, it seems that I need to use HTTP.net but it generate an issue.

Comment: My solution is based on Python.